# Ran out of GPU memory when allocating 0 bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, mnist

i modified the Deep Mnist example on the tensorflow website to the following:

```
a = np.zeros((5500,10))
a = mnist.train.labels.copy()

batchsize = 250

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):
        batch = [mnist.train.images[i:batchsize], a[i:batchsize]]
        if i % 10 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
        del batch

    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

What i did was just creating my own batch of mnist.datasets with a custom label array.

But when i run this, after some iterations, I get the following output:

```
Ran out of GPU memory when allocating 0 bytes for 
 [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_6 = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape_20, Reshape_21)]]
```

I even added those lines:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

and nvidia-smi tells me, that arround 4Gb's should be free.

Does anyone know this problem or maybe even knows, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
batch = [mnist.train.images[i:batchsize], a[i:batchsize]]
```

will give you empty batches as soon as `i >= batchsize`. In fact, the error message you posted says `Ran out of GPU memory when allocating 0 bytes`.

What you probably want is (note the added `i+`):

```
batch = [mnist.train.images[i:i+batchsize], a[i:i+batchsize]]
```

**EDIT**

The code should also increase `i` by batch size in order not to re-use samples during one training epoch:

```
for i in range(0,1000, batchsize):
```

Note that the code also does not loop over the full sample, you could do this by doing:

```
for i in range(0,len(a), batchsize):
```

Furthermore it is recommended to loop over the samples in random order. This is important if you loop over the sample more than once (you may get the same gradient steps as in the previous iteration), also to avoid any effects due to a particular ordering of the training sample (e.g. learn all zero first, then all ones and finish with the nines your network may tend to classify too many things as nines).

Comment: Thank u very much!! I gonna kill myself now, so obvious :D